# how to login through ionic app and authenticate by creating a RESTful service in PHP?

Tags: php, ionic-framework, restful-authentication

I am trying to login through ionic app and the user should get authenticated RESTfuly in PHP...

Frontend: Ionic Framework
Backend: Php (RESTful service)

Please provide a useful tutorial...

Comment: may be this could help u to start : http://devdactic.com/simple-login-example-with-ionic-and-angularjs/ and  http://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/

Comment: I am ok with ionic thing, well i want to know how to use php at the backend...